# C# Polymorphysm: overloading function, accepting delegates Action<T> and Func<T,R>?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, polymorphism

Here's a simple code, where I try to implement some sort of polymorphysm.

You can see overloaded `Invoker` function, accepting `Func<T,R>` and `Action<T>` as an argument.

Compiler says it couldn't be compiled because of ambiguity if Invoker methods:

```
class Program
{
    static void Invoker(Action<XDocument> parser)
    {
    }

    static void Invoker(Func<XDocument,string> parser)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Invoker(Action);
        Invoker(Function);
    }

    static void Action(XDocument x)
    {
    }

    static string Function(XDocument x)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I get 3(!) errors, and none of it i can explain. Here they are:

> Error 1   **The call is ambiguous** between the following methods or properties: 'ConsoleApplication3.Program.Invoker(System.Action)' and 'ConsoleApplication3.Program.Invoker(System.Func)' c:\users\i.smagin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs  21  4   ConsoleApplication3
>
> Error 2   **The call is ambiguous** between the following methods or properties: 'ConsoleApplication3.Program.Invoker(System.Action)' and 'ConsoleApplication3.Program.Invoker(System.Func)' c:\users\i.smagin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs  22  4   ConsoleApplication3
>
> Error 3   'string ConsoleApplication3.Program.Function(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument)' **has the wrong return type**  c:\users\i.smagin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs  22  12  ConsoleApplication3

Any ideas?

Comment: I merged your answer as a supplemental addition to your question. If you want to ask a whole new question, just roll back my edit and do so. Please, only post answers as answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both

```
static void Action(XDocument x)
```

and

```
static string Function(XDocument x)
```

have same method signature.

Return value is not part of method signature. So, just having a different return type won't work. They must have different number of parameters or parameter types must be different.

Since, compiler cannot figure out which one (method that takes `Action` or method that takes `Func`) to use, you have to explicitly specify it:

```
Invoker(new Action<XDocument>(Action));
Invoker(new Func<XDocument, String>(Function));
```

to resolve ambiguity.

Comment: Does this mean that Func<XDocument,string> Action<XDocument> are same? If yes, than why can i compile program without calling method Invoker?

Comment: No, they are not same. But, compiler cannot figure out which one to use since they have same signatures.

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke your methods like that:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Invoker(new Action<XDocument>(Action));
     Invoker(new Func<XDocument, string> (Function));
}
```

Simply, you have to tell compiler what method you want to invoke.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more elegant solution using linq:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Invoker((xdocument)=>doSomething);      // calls action invoker
     Invoker((xdocument)=>{return doSomething;}); // calls function invoker
}
```

At the end of it... comes down to signatures.

Comment: There's no LINQ here. Lambdas are used in LINQ, but they are not LINQ.